# Internationalization CoreText Framework issue iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift

Application crashed iOS 11 in CoreText Framework for Hindi Language text

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreText                       0x185d393a8 TRunGlue::SeparateCharactersInGlyphRange(CFRange) + 68
1  CoreText                       0x185d393a8 TRunGlue::SeparateCharactersInGlyphRange(CFRange) + 68
2  CoreText                       0x185d394dc TRunGlue::RotateRight(CFRange, long) + 144
3  CoreText                       0x185d9ccf0 OpenTypeShapingEngine::ApplyScriptShaping(unsigned int*) + 308
4  CoreText                       0x185d3c654 void TOpenTypeMorph::ApplyShapingEngine<TInlineVector<unsigned int, 30ul> >(OTL::GSUB&, OTL::GlyphLookups&, unsigned int*, CFRange, TInlineVector<unsigned int, 30ul>&, SyncState&, bool*) + 2472
5  CoreText                       0x185d3b87c TOpenTypeMorph::ShapeGlyphs(SyncState&, bool*) + 340
6  CoreText                       0x185cd8d14 TShapingEngine::ShapeGlyphs(TLine&, TCharStream const&) + 240
7  CoreText                       0x185cdd514 TTypesetter::FinishEncoding(std::__1::tuple<TLine const*, TCharStream const*, void const* (*)(__CTRun const*, __CFString const*, void*), void*, std::__1::shared_ptr<TBidiLevelsProvider>*, unsigned int, unsigned char> const&, TLine&, signed char) + 256
8  CoreText                       0x185ca833c TTypesetterAttrString::Initialize(__CFAttributedString const*) + 668
9  CoreText                       0x185ca7f74 TTypesetterAttrString::TTypesetterAttrString(__CFAttributedString const*) + 112
10 CoreText                       0x185ca7e58 CTLineCreateWithAttributedString + 52
11 UIFoundation                   0x18ca5e710 -[NSCoreTypesetter _NSStringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:context:forceClipping:usesWebKitCompatibleMetrics:attributes:options:drawingContext:wantsTextLineFragments:validatedAttributedString:firstNonRenderedCharacterIndex:foundSoftHyphenAtEOL:enginePathUsed:] + 840
```